# incremento de folio en php

Tags: php, html

Hola Buen día quisiera solicitar ayuda ya que tengo un formulario el unico problema que tengo es que quiero hacer que el folio en este caso OT(Orden de trabajo)sea de manera autoincrementable.
La parte de donde estan los 4 ceros es donde quiero que sea automatico quisiera saber si hay posibilidad.
Por el momento el ingreso es de manera manual como se puede reflejar aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo del formulario es este

```html
<div id="new_project" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog"> 
               <div class="modal-content modal-md">  
             
                  <div class="modal-header"> 
                     <h3 class="modal-title" id='head'>
                      <p ALIGN=right  >
                     <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-close"  ></i>X</button>
              </p> 
                     <center> <i class=""></i> Nuevo Servicio
                     </h3> </center>
                 
                  </div> 
<form method="POST" id='proj_form'  > 
 <div class="modal-body">
  
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div id="retCode2">
               <div class="alert alert-success" id="suc_msg2">
               <h4><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Datos agregados correctamente.</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="alert alert-danger" id="err_msg2">
               <h4><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Error al cargar.</h4>
             </div>
             </div>
             </div>
        </div> <option id="p_typ"></option>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Orden de Trabajo:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" style="text-transform:capitalize" autocomplete="off" id="" name="pname" type="text" value="OT0000-23">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btn_sub"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-close"></i>Cerrar</button>
            </form>
                     </div>
                     </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
```

el codigo para agregarlo en la base de datos es este

```
if($action == 'project'){
$pname =$_POST['pname'];

    
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO projects (project)
    VALUES('$pname')");
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

}

Comment: Si se guarda en una DB, haces una query, traes el último dato y le sumas 1.

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el resultado de `show create table projects`.

Comment: ¿Como seria eso? @OCHOA

Comment: ¿De cual hablas? @Sal

Comment: Hacerlo como dice @OCHOA tiene su riesgo, aunque puede funcionar para tareas, no es la mejor manera. Es mejor el autoincrementable, por eso primero debes confirmarnos que tu columna esta declarada como.

Comment: @Sal, se parte de que no lo tiene así. Si lo hace `autoincrement` seria lo ideal. Es más ese tipo de dato yo lo manejo como `int` y luego le pongo la "máscara", más optimo aun. Y riesgo, que no sea lo más optimo lo acepto pero riesgo, donde??

Comment: En este caso la columna lo manejo como varchar, porque necesito las letras OT entonces no se si habria algun problema?

Comment: Lo puede manejar como `autoincrement`?? Si es así, luego con código le puede agregar la "máscara" con las letras o símbolos que usted necesite, es más puede dejar esa "máscara" como un parámetro en la DB por si a futuro cambia. Sorry, debo salir de la oficina y no regreso en varios días. Espero pueda solventarlo, la verdad no está tan difícil. Ánimos!!!

Comment: Para que te funcione `mysqli_insert_id()` debe ser númerico y con AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: @OCHOA en un ambiente multiusuario, mientras no hagas un commit, multiples usuarios pueden terminar con el mismo numero... es un NO rotundo..

Comment: Estas mezclando cosas @Paola. una cosa es el formato, y otra los valores... que es ese OT??? todos los datos de esa tabla son OT??? esos numeros que queres hacer automaticos, se reinician??? porque ahi entran 10000 nada mas... esto va mas alla de decir, quiero hacerlo automatico...

Comment: @gbianchi okay solo quiero que al momento de insertar la OT(orden de trabajo) sea de manera consecutica ejemplo OT0001-23, OT0002-23, OT0003-23 y asi consecutivamente.

Comment: @gbianchi tuve que actualizar un sistema así (que no era mío obvio) y antes de hacer el insert consultaba el último y le sumaba uno. Un sistema que se usaba a nivel nacional y nunca tuve problemas con eso. Todo está en hacerlo bien y con los controles necesarios para que lo que tu dices no se de, pero es totalmente válido tu punto. Creo que fue un coment muy básico de mi parte, creo que es porque mi mente ya está en otra cosa.

Comment: @Paola entonces por lo que decis, OT es un conjunto de datos que contempla el año (el 23) un numero de orden, que espero que te alcancen, y una palabra adelante... entonces... tu clave deberia ser solo el numero del medio, y cuando queres recuperar, usar el año tambien.. pero todo eso NO DEBERIA estar en un campo, porque es un tema de formato.. imaginate si queres ordenar.. o si queres buscar.. un desastre.. saca todo lo que no sea obvio de ahi...

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a tu problema: en alguna tabla de tu base de datos (o incluso en una tabla independiente, si es necesario) creas un campo llamado 'siguiente', el cual contendrá el *siguiente* número de OT.

Al crear una nueva orden, recuperas ese campo y lo asignas como número de ot:

```
// Recuperas el número de la columna 'siguiente' y lo asignas a una variable   
// ($siguiente) y agregas los ceros a la izquierda
$numero_ot = str_pad($siguiente, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

// Creas el identificador de tu OT
$ot = "OT" . $numero_ot . "-23";

//incrementas $numero_siguiente
$numero_siguiente++;

// Y continúas con el código para almacenar $numero_siguiente en la base de datos
```

Saludos